# How can I decorate all my bindings implementing a specific interface in Ninject

Tags: ninject, mediatr

I'm using Jimmy Bogard's Mediatr and trying to use the pipleine example [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/09/09/tackling-cross-cutting-concerns-with-a-mediator-pipeline/)

my problem is that although I can get all my closing generic types like so

```
     kernel.Bind(
            x =>
                x.FromAssemblyContaining<ExpensiveRequest>()
                    .SelectAllClasses()
                    .InheritedFrom(typeof (IRequestHandler<,>)).BindAllInterfaces()
```

I can't decorate them all with the MediatorPipeline.

So if I were using StructureMap I could use something like this

```
cfg.For(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(MediatorPipeline<,>));
```

I can't find how I would achieve it with Ninject so that when when my Mediator is called it uses the Mediator pipeline and then down to the original Handler

Comment: care to post your answer yourself? https://github.com/MrKevHunter/RedisMediatorClient

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I want to know how to do this for a pattern like https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91, where I want to be able to register one or more decorators for my `ICommandHandler<T>` generics.

Comment: it's in the github repo above

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways to do this. You can either do a convention based scan which you are already doing, and add a contextual binding to the end of it:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssemblyContaining<ExpensiveRequest>()
     .SelectAllClasses()
     .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
     .BindAllInterfaces();
     .Configure(c => c.WhenInjectedExactlyInto(typeof(MediatorPipeline<,>));
```

Then just do the exact same thing again *without* the `WhenInjectedExactlyInto` context filter:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssemblyContaining<ExpensiveRequest>()
     .SelectAllClasses()
     .InheritedFrom(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
     .BindAllInterfaces();
```

This would require two assembly scans to happen though.

Another way would be to write an IBindingGenerator, and perform multiple bindings in there - one with `WhenInjectedExactlyInto` and another without. This would then only require a single convention based binding using the `.BindWith<MyBindingGenerator>()` syntax instead of `.BindAllInterfaces()`